# Specific regex pattern to stop advertisement

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the php function preg_match() to check for a specific pattern.

I've gone through about 50 websites so far, and still haven't figured out how to do this specific pattern.

If there is the word "dot" or "d0t" after anything and before anything that contains "com" or "org", it would catch it.

I'm making something that filters out advertisement, it separately filters out anything except for letters, numbers, and underscores; that has to stay separate. It has it's own purpose, and it's own output.

If you can help me figure out how to do this, or link me to anything that I may have missed after 2 hours of googling, I would so greatly appreciate it.
Thanks.

Comment: For instance, it would filter out this:
som3thin dot com

somethinn_ dot __CoM

somethin dot com

somethnngg134sdfa ___ d0t orggg

etc.. :\

Comment: Post some of your code that you tried.

Comment: I've tried tons of different regex patterns, none of which have worked. I've got like one left on my clipboard, but it's not even close to correct. Lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is not very clear but you can try this regex for preg_match:

```
'~d[0o]t.*?(?:com|org)~i'
```

`This matches word "dot" or "d0t" before anything that contains "com" or "org"`

Comment: Sorry about that, these things get really complicated, thus it's hard to explain. I'll try it out. Looks like it'll work.

Comment: I did this:
'~d[0o]t.*?(?:com|org)~i`
that's what it appears on ur answer

Comment: Try edited code. Sorry I used reverse quote by mistake earlier.

Comment: Oh, okay. I thought it might be that but wasn't sure. Thanks it works!! :D Hasn't been 3 mins yet..I'll confirm ur answer when I get home. THanks man.

Comment: Please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.